# Activerecordの更新のメソッドを使っているのに、idがuniqueではないYOと出る。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

```
product = <Item id: 4, url: nil, memo: nil, created_at: "2015-11-07 09:48:36", updated_at: "2015-11-07 09:48:36", Totalweight: 390.0, Perweight: nil, price: 1000>
attr = {"id"=>4, "tag_list"=>"peanuts", "price"=>1000, "url"=>nil, "Totalweight"=>390, "memo"=>nil}
```

で、

```
product.update!(attr)
```

ないしは、

```
product.update_attributes!(attr)
```

で、activerecordを更新しようとしていますが、

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException　UNIQUE constraint failed: items.id
!! #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: items.id: INSERT INTO "items" ("id", "price", "Totalweight", "created_at", "updated_at", "url") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)>
```

とエラーがでてしまいます。

Activerecordのupdateメソッドはidが同じという条件下に使用するものではないのでしょうか？
IDがUniqueじゃない！　と言われてももちろんそうYO!と思ってしまうのですが、、
どうやってidが同じものを更新すればよいのでしょうか？
ググってもupdate, update_attributes, update_attributeしかでてきませんでした。

idがなければ、新しくインスタンスを作り、saveし、
そのidのレコードがあれば、更新するというようにしたいのです。

追記
エクセル, CSVのスプレッドシートを読み込むgemを使用しておりまして、
def self.import(file)のメソッドの、spreadsheetを読み込んだ
後、rowメソッドはgem rooによるものです。

gem "roo"
https://github.com/roo-rb/roo

```
  COLUMN = ["id","tag_list","price","url","Perweight","Totalweight", "memo", "id", "created_at", "updated_at"]

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      if Item.find(row["id"]) then
        product = Item.new
        attr = row.slice(*COLUMN)
        # product.attributes = attr
        #updateやupdate_attributesには引数をハッシュで渡すよう。
        product.update(attr)
      else
        product = Item.new
        attr = row.slice(*COLUMN)
        product.attributes = attr
        product.save!
      end


    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then
      Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path, extension: :csv)
    when ".xls" then
      Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path, extension: :xls)
    when ".xlsx" then
      Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path, extension: :xlsx)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Product モデルの定義や validation に依るものかもしれませんので、
問題ない範囲で Product モデルのコードを掲載しては如何でしょうか？

Comment: そもそも発行されているSQLがUPDATEではなくINSERTであることが気になります。どこかでデータを作っている処理はありませんか？

Comment: 念の為に確認しますが、実際に読み込んでいるスプレッドシートファイルの一行目はヘッダ行ですよね？

Comment: そうです、一行目はヘッダ行になります。
それ以降をgem "roo"で読み込んでいます。
activerecordのメソッドupdateやupdate_attributesを使用すれば、
SQLになるんではないでしょうか・・（すいませんSQL詳しくないですが、確かに現状insertになっております）

Comment: そのヘッダ行なのですけれども、差支えなければ質問欄に追記していただけますか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: それと、今気が付いたのですが、`COLUMN = ["id", ...]` に `"id"` が2つ入っています。これは記載ミスでしょうか？

Comment: 確かに、ミスしています！！
id tag_list price Totalweight Perweight url memo
になります、削除したのち試してみます。

Comment: ちなみに、saveメソッドは使えるのでvalidationは関係ないとおもわれます・・。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何故かわかりました！
同じidを持つItemオブジェクトを２つ作成しているのが原因です。
更新する場合は、そのidのattributesを更新するように挿入する必要があり、
idは同じオブジェクトであっても、さらにオブジェクトを入れることはできないようです。

ここからは憶測ですが、オブジェクトにid以外の固有の何か識別するものが与えられているものだからだと思われます。オブジェクトを生成した際に、１６進数のアレかなとおもってます↑

```
product = Item.find(row["id"])
if product then
  attr = row.slice(*COLUMN)
  # 更新する。
  product.update(attr)
else
...
end
```

か

```
# idが存在するか確かめ, なければ新しいidを作ってイニシャライズする。
product = Item.find_or_initialize_by(id: row["id"])
attr = row.slice(*COLUMN)
product.attributes = attr
product.save!
```

ルールとしてやっていいのか分からなかったですが、英語のstackoverflowにても質問しました↑
リンクは[update method of ActiveRecord failed because UNIQUE constraint failed: items.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585569/update-method-of-activerecord-failed-because-unique-constraint-failed-items-id)
になります。
上記の内容は、質問に回答頂いたNilsさんの回答をもとに意訳してあります。

というわけで、回答を締め切らせて頂きます。
ありがとうございました！！！